# How to compute the average for every n number in a list

Tags: c#

Having a List of numbers, I want to take every n(e.g. 5 , 10 , etc.) element, compute their average and put the average in a new list. As an example lets assume we have the following list:
1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 
Now we compute the average every 2 elements and we will get the following list as output: 
1.5 , 3.5 , 5.5 , 7.5 
How can I do that?

Comment: What have you attempted to do so far to solve this problem, and what problems are you having with your attempted solutions?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: @mituw16: I can't come up with a good algorithm for this, whatever I've done there was a flaw in it.

Comment: Okay, that's not a problem! Post what you have tried so that we can help point you in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public List<double> Average(List<double> number, int nElement)
    {
        var currentElement = 0;
        var currentSum = 0.0;

        var newList = new List<double>();

        foreach (var item in number)
        {
            currentSum += item;
            currentElement++;

            if(currentElement == nElement)
            {
                newList.Add(currentSum / nElement);
                currentElement = 0;
                currentSum = 0.0;
            }
        }
        // Maybe the array element count is not the same to the asked, so average the last sum. You can remove this condition if you want
        if(currentElement > 0)
        {
            newList.Add(currentSum / currentElement);
        }

        return newList;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a for-loop and `Enumerable.Average`:

```
var averages = new List<double>();
for (int i = 0; i < ints.Length; i += 2)
{
    int thisInt = ints[i];
    int nextInt = i == ints.Length - 1 ? thisInt : ints[i + 1];
    averages.Add(new[] { thisInt, nextInt }.Average());
}
```

Here's a dynamic approach that works with any length:

```
int take = 2;
for (int i = 0; i < ints.Length; i += take)
{
    if(i + take >= ints.Length)
        take = ints.Length - i;
    int[] subArray = new int[take];
    Array.Copy(ints, i, subArray, 0, take);
    averages.Add(subArray.Average());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is just testing your use of iteration and the modulus operator. Modulus gives you the remainder of division, you can use it to check whether or not the current number should be included in the average as you iterate the array. Here is a sample method;

```
public float nthsAverage(int n, int[] numbers)
{
     // quick check to avoid a divide by 0 error
     if (numbers.Length  == 0)
        return 0;

     int sum = 0;
     int count = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
     {
         // might want i+1 here instead to compensate for array being 0 indexed, ie 9th number is at the 8th index
         if (i % n == 0)
         {
              sum = sum + numbers[i];
              count++; 
         }
     }
     return (float)sum / count;
}
```

Comment: I thought about this but what will happen if for the last step the if statement is not true? then the last numbers will be left out.

Comment: @Erik if the if statement is not true it means the number is not every `n`. For example if I have 9 items in a collection and `n` is three it will give me the third, and sixth item (maybe it should use i + 1 since arrays are zero indexed and people don't think of lists in that manner typically, then it would give me third, sixth and ninth, in my code i will be 8 on last index). Basically the if statement filters only the nth numbers, I add their values to the sum then divide that by the count giving you the average of the nth numbers only.